# One of Windows installations on the disk fails to boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, uefi, gpt

I have two Windows 10 installations on the same GPT disk; today, one of these installations stopped booting while another one works without problems. The booting process gets to the stage where it asks to choose the Windows installation to boot to, I choose the failing one and then it shows the "automatic repair failed" message.
Any ideas what can be broken and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a separate license for each Windows installation?

Comment: @John not really. Is it actually required in this case? I mean, it's the same PC.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to repair the bootloader. When the error message comes, select Advanced options. Now go to Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command prompt. Now run `bootrec /rebuildbcd & bootrec /fixmbr & bootrec /fixboot`. Now run `chkdsk /r` on each partition's drive letter.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm getting a message that says "The system cannot find the file specified" on any of these commands.